# Android App Doesn't Stay in Portrait Mode

Tags: android, android-manifest

So I've set my manifest to keep the app in portrait mode, as this is how the game should be played. However, despite doing what I've seen others do, it still switches modes when you tilt the phone. Below is what I've done with the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      ...
      android:screenOrientation="portrait">

...
<activity android:name=".GameActivity"
                  ...
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always used

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

in each `<activity>` to good effect. Give it a shot.